# My View constraints are grayed out, This view holds a UICOLLECTIONVIEW

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard, constraints

I have this view and i want to add constraints to it to be zero to top, lead, trail of the Main view
Yet when i want to add them its grayed out[image: Its grayed out and i cannot change it]

Comment: are you copy pasting this view from somewhere? This happend to me when i tried copying table header view to another view ..

Comment: No i just created it like any other content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the `Layout` property is set to `Automatic` instead of `Translates Mask Into Constraints` in the `Size Inspector` tab on the right side of Xcode. The interphase builder won't let you add constraints if you have set the `Layout` property to `Translates Mask Into Constraints` in `Size Inspector`.

[image: Xcode Size Inspector]